# Android ListView scroll to top without highlighting first item

Tags: android, android-listview, highlight

I use `list.setSelection(0);` to scroll the `ListView` to top, but this also unfortunately sets the highlight color of the top list item.

I just want it to scroll to top and not set the highlight color. (Android API 10)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [smoothScrollToPositionFromTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(int,%20int)).

try

```
list.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(0, 0);
```

or

```
list.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(list.getHeaderViewsCount(), 0);
```

if your ListView has header.

Comment: smoothScroll also highlights the top item unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
list.smoothScrollBy(0, 1000);
```

or

```
if (!ListView.isStackFromBottom()) {
    ListView.setStackFromBottom(true);
}
ListView.setStackFromBottom(false);
```

Comment: Please explain why these solutions would work/what they do instead of just suggesting them.